# problem with form data (View & Controller & Routing) in Codeigniter 4.3.3

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-4

i am trying to get data on Controller from view but not getting anything just blank array.

**View Page**

```html
<form action="<?=base_url();?>appointment/" method="post" name="rulesForm">
  <div class="form-group mt-3">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input style="height: 14px;" type="checkbox" name="rulescheck" id="rulescheck" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" name="rulesSubmit" id="rulesSubmit">Submit</button></div>
</form>
```

**Controller Page**

```
public function rules()
{
    helper('form');
    return view('pages/rules')
}


public function appointmentForm()
{
    helper('form');
    $data = $this->request->getPost();
    
    print_r($data);
}
```

**Route Page**

```
$routes->get('appointment', 'Appointment::appointmentForm');
```

i tried changing the route to

```
$routes->post('appointment', 'Appointment::appointmentForm');
```

i am getting this error

> 404 Can't find a route for 'get: appointment'.

now i am using this route

```
$routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'rules', [Appointment::class, 'rules']);
$routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'appointment', [Appointment::class, 'appointmentForm']);
```

but still no data in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with trailing '/' on the form action.
I tried this instead and everything is fine now

```
<form action="<?= base_url('appointment'); ?>" method="post" name="rulesForm">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, this will work for me :

Routes :

```
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->get('/rules', 'Home::rules');
$routes->post('/appointment', 'Home::appointmentForm');
```

Home Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{

    public function rules()
    {
        helper('form');
        return view('pages/rules');
    }
    
    
    public function appointmentForm()
    {
        helper('form');
        $data = $this->request->getPost();        
        print_r($data);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

View File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?=base_url();?>appointment/" method="post" name="rulesForm">
  <div class="form-group mt-3">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input style="height: 14px;" type="checkbox" name="rulescheck" id="rulescheck" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" name="rulesSubmit" id="rulesSubmit">Submit</button></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]